# JSON.parse error on a seemingly valid JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, laravel-5

I'm using `JSON.parse()` to parse a `json` that's being returned from an api (Laravel 5) called using jquery's `$.get()`. The `json` is seemingly valid, however, `JSON.parse()` is returning error in both Safari and Chrome.

Chrome says:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
```

Safari says:

```
SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "object"
```

The code fragment is as below:

```
    $.get('/foo/' + product_id, function(data){
        console.log(data);
        var product = JSON.parse(data);
        if (product) {
            // do something
        }
     });
```

The JSON is:

```
{  
   "id":"1b7b3eb7-8769-48fe-a421-64c105de3eff",
   "parent":null,
   "org_id":"845d0d53-de68-42c3-9007-c3d0e72c555e",
   "category_id":"e58237f7-e040-4098-8d46-b84f8cdf7d83",
   "purchase_tax":null,
   "sale_tax":null,
   "code":"982",
   "name":"Mr. Destin Hoppe",
   "is_purchased":false,
   "is_sold":false,
   "purchase_price":null,
   "selling_price":null,
   "purchase_includes_tax":false,
   "sale_includes_tax":false,
   "created_at":"2015-09-16 17:39:34",
   "updated_at":"2015-09-16 17:39:34"
}
```

Interestingly, `eval()` works just fine.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The error is a result of `data` being an object, not JSON. You don't need to parse anything; it is already a JavaScript object. jQuery does the parsing within its `get` method. To confirm this, add this line to the top of the callback.

```
console.log(data["id"]);
```

As another example of this error, the following line will also fail for the same reason.

```
JSON.parse({});
```

Comment: Since when? Agreed I'm using jquery after years, but last I used it, it used to be a string (or was it?)

Comment: @CodePoet It's been that way for years.

Comment: Ah. I think I see it now, the Response header says `Content-Type: application/json`, maybe that's why?

Comment: You can identify the response type in the client-side call and/or the server-side code. Perhaps you never did thus jQuery didn't have enough information to do the job for you.

Comment: @CodePoet: From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/): *"Different types of response to $.ajax() call are subjected to different kinds of pre-processing before being passed to the success handler. The type of pre-processing depends by default upon the Content-Type of the response, but can be set explicitly using the dataType option."*

Comment: @FelixKling Right. I have used `dataType` in the past to ensure that jQuery knows JSON is coming back. Alternatively, the `getJSON` method could be used, which is shorthand for the same: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the api's I was using then, weren't setting `Content-Type`, because I wrote those api's too. Silly me :)